# jOOQ fetch vs fetchResultSet and close connection in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jooq, hikaricp

I'm using Kotlin with HikariCP and jOOQ to query my database. I've come to realize that this code works as expected, fetching the rows and closing the connection afterwards:

```
class CountriesService(private val datasource: DataSource) {

    private val countries = Countries()

    fun getCountries(): List<String> {
        DSL.using(datasource, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
            .use { ctx ->
                ctx.select(countries.CO_NAME)
                    .from(countries)
                    .orderBy(countries.CO_NAME)
                    .fetch()
                return emptyList()
            }
    }
}
```

whereas if I use `fetchResultSet()`, the connection is never closed and the pool dries out:

```
class CountriesService(private val datasource: DataSource) {

    private val countries = Countries()

    fun getCountries(): List<String> {
        DSL.using(datasource, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
            .use { ctx ->
                ctx.select(countries.CO_NAME)
                    .from(countries)
                    .orderBy(countries.CO_NAME)
                    .fetchResultSet()
                return emptyList()
            }
    }
}
```

I've seen that `AbstractResultQuery#fetchResultSet()` is delegating to a `fetchLazy()` method, so not sure if it has something to do with that.

If I get the connection myself instead of delegating it to the `DSLContext`, then it works:

```
class CountriesService(private val datasource: DataSource) {

    private val countries = Countries()

    fun getCountries(): List<String> {
        val conn = datasource.connection
        conn.use {
            DSL.using(it, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
                .select(countries.CO_NAME)
                .from(countries)
                .orderBy(countries.CO_NAME)
                .fetchResultSet()
            return emptyList()
        }
    }
}
```

Is this last approach the one I should be using?

Comment: Why do you want to fetch the JDBC `ResultSet` in the first place? Your code does not hint at this being useful for you. Also, why return `emptyList()` each time?

Comment: @LukasEder Well, yeah, maybe it's not the most explicit example, just wanted something fast to show my problem, sorry for that. I need the `ResultSet` because then I'm using SimpleFlatMapper to produce a result with a many-to-many relationship as explained in this post https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2017/02/27/jooq-one-to-many.html, something like `MyClass.mapper.stream(rs).toList()` (the mapper is in MyClass' companion object). Let me update the question.

Comment: Hmm, maybe, rather than updating the question (because my answer can still be useful as it is right now, to others), can you ask a new one that is more complete? Here are some guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly as specified in the [Javadoc](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchResultSet--):

> This is the same as calling `fetchLazy().resultSet()` and will return a `ResultSet` wrapping the JDBC driver's `ResultSet`. Closing this ResultSet may close the producing `Statement` or `PreparedStatement`, depending on your setting for `keepStatement(boolean)`.

The point of this method is that you want to consume a JDBC result set rather than having jOOQ consume it for you. So, you're responsible for the resource management.

Given your example code, you should definitely not call this method but call `fetch()` instead. For example:

```
class CountriesService(private val datasource: DataSource) {

    private val countries = Countries()

    fun getCountries(): List<String> {
        return
        DSL.using(datasource, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
           .select(countries.CO_NAME)
           .from(countries)
           .orderBy(countries.CO_NAME)
           .fetch(countries.CO_NAME)
    }
}
```

Notice, you don't need to call that `use()` method on your `DSLContext`. While `DSLContext` extends `AutoCloseable`, this is only needed when your `DSLContext` manages the underlying JDBC connection (i.e. when it creates it). In your case, when you pass a data source to `DSL.using()`, then you don't have to close the `DSLContext`.