# jOOQ fetchResultSet not closing connection with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jooq, hikaricp

I'm using Kotlin with HikariCP and jOOQ to query my database. I've come to realize that this code works as expected, fetching the rows and closing the connection afterwards:

```
class CountriesService(private val datasource: DataSource) {

    private val countries = Countries()

    fun getCountries(): List<Country> {
        DSL.using(datasource, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
            .use { ctx ->
                return ctx.select(...)
                    .from(...)
                    .orderBy(...)
                    .fetch(Country.mapper) // val mapper: (CountriesRecord) -> Country = {...}
            }
    }
}
```

This mapper was no longer suitable after adding a many-to-many relationship to `Country`, so I wanted to get a `ResultSet` and with SimpleFlatMapper produce objects with this relationship (as explained on [this link](https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2017/02/27/jooq-one-to-many.html)), but with `fetchResultSet()` the connection is never closed and the pool dries out:

```
class CountriesService(private val datasource: DataSource) {

    private val countries = Countries()

    fun getCountries(): List<Country> {
        DSL.using(datasource, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
            .use { ctx ->
                val rs = ctx.select(...)
                    .from(...)
                    .orderBy(...)
                    .fetchResultSet()
                return Country.mapper.stream(rs).toList() // val mapper = JdbcMapperFactory.newInstance()...
            }
    }
}
```

I've seen that `AbstractResultQuery#fetchResultSet()` is delegating to a `fetchLazy()` method, so not sure if it has something to do with that.

If I get the connection myself instead of delegating it to the `DSLContext`, then it works:

```
class CountriesService(private val datasource: DataSource) {

    private val countries = Countries()

    fun getCountries(): List<Country> {
        val conn = datasource.connection
        conn.use {
            val rs = DSL.using(it, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)
                .select(...)
                .from(...)
                .orderBy(...)
                .fetchResultSet()
            return Country.mapper.stream(rs).toList() // val mapper = JdbcMapperFactory.newInstance()...
        }
    }
}
```

Is this last approach the one I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that produces a resource is always responsible for closing it. And that's you. And the resource is the `ResultSet`. Your code should look like this instead:

```kotlin
class CountriesService(private val datasource: DataSource) {

    private val countries = Countries()

    fun getCountries(): List<Country> {
        val ctx = DSL.using(datasource, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_10)

        return
        ctx.select(...)
           .from(...)
           .orderBy(...)
           .fetchResultSet()
           .use {
                return Country.mapper.stream(it).toList()
            }
    }
}
```

#### About calling `DSLContext.use`

Notice, just like [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334957/521799), I recommend you do not call `use` on jOOQ's `DSLContext` type, as you don't need it. In your case, `DSLContext` is not resourceful as you pass it a `datasource`

#### About calling `ResultSet.use`

Instead, you should call `use` on `ResultSet`, which guarantees that it is closed after consumption. In this example, I'm assuming that your call to `toList()` will eagerly consume the entire stream that wraps the result set.

The important thing to remember here is that *you* produce the resource by calling jOOQ's `ResultQuery.fetchResultSet()`, and even if you pass it to another library, that other library is not required to close it. But *you* are.